# Need help POST is crashing server

Tags: mongodb, express

Can anyone see why, this would crash my app server?

// note_routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.post('/notes', (req, res) => 
    {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('Hello')
  });
};
```

I am following the tutorial on how to build a simple node server api on medium, https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

Yet, I cant figure out how to get past this error?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call this function during your server initialization?  And, when it "crashes", what exactly does the error say?  You have to show us more of your code and give us the exact error because there's nothing obviously wrong with these lines of code so the problem is likely elsewhere, probably in how this is getting called.

Comment: jfreind, thankyou for the tip. in the server.js file, I had written, require('./app/routes')('app',{});, when it should have been ...(app, {}). Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

To close off this question, I'll summarize in an answer.

`app` needs to be passed as a function reference, not as a string.

Change this:

```
 require('./app/routes')('app',{})
```

to this:

```
 require('./app/routes')(app,{})
```